# Is tezos-node single or multi-threaded?

Tags: node, performance, scalability

Does the `tezos-node` work on the mempool in a single or multithreaded fashion ?

Would it be useful/necessary or not in order to scale-up the throughput of the chain when the number of transactions to validate will grow ?

NB: just noticed this [merge request](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/merge_requests/757) that seems to go in the direction of allowing multiple processes to validate blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of the Tezos node is mono-threaded. Indeed, there is work in the direction of parallelisation, it is probably better to do so through multiple processes than through multithreading, more error prone.